# user notification system design

Tags: php, design-patterns, database-design, notifications

I'm trying to make a user notification system(like facebook)
I have mysql tables which simplified like  ;

```
user : id,username
post : id,user_id,text
comment:id,user_id,post_id,text
post_like:id,post_id,user_id
friend:id,owner_id,follower_id
```

You can see the relations between tables.. This notification system should allow to user track comments under a post which owner of a post or touched to the post(like or comment),
track like action on a post which owner of a post or touched to the post(like or comment),
notify friendship actions and similars.

First I think to solve it with another tables ;

```
notification: id,notification_type,user_owner,user_other,isNotified,date
ntype:id,type (such as friendship,add a comment, like a post etc.)
```

So when a user make an action I'll just insert the action on notification table then on client I'll check with ajax the logged user has any notification(with isNotified=false)
after that just update isNotified=true.

In this scenario how can i notify other users which touch a post (commented or liked).. It's just notifiying to owner of post in this case..

Also while i'm researching find [the notification queque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315991/design-pattern-notification-system), I think it's better way to implement something like that.. So can you give some details about how to imlement a notification queque..

I'm also curious about performance issues about it.. Let say what happens if have 100K user and each user has 10 post and 100 comments,likes daily. Then what will happen?
Should i consider some nosql solutions for this job such as neo4G or mongodb?
Thank you..