# Standard Design Pattern for building a Social Notification System for Android -

Tags: android, push-notification, server-side, google-cloud-messaging, polling

Working on a social app that has alot of the standard social networking features such as friend requests, private messages and comments and im in need of a real time or near real time notification system. Ive looked into GCM a bit and done a few tuts.

My question is how should my server side be structured ? what is the standard pattern when it comes to implementing a near realtime social notification system? Ive found lots of tuts that focus on just getting GCM up and running , but how a system overall should be structured is still vague. For simplicity lets use a private messaging system as a example, from what ive gathered it seems that the way it goes is:

- User A Types message  >>
- User A hits submit >>
- Message is sent from the client to the server to be processed by the
  API  >>
- Message reaches API where its processed using the sendMessage
  function >>
- Inside the sendMessage function the message is validated and written
  to the db  >>
- Inside the sendMessage function  if(message_inserted_into_db){ send
  notification to GCM}
- Code is setup on the Android client side to retrieve notifications
  from GCM

Am I missing any other steps? Are there any other things that should trigger sending notifications? Should i use push exclusively or a combination of push and poll?

Id like to make it very clear I AM NOT CONFUSED ABOUT HOW TO IMPLEMENT GCM ON A TECHNICAL LEVEL...so
please do not post a link to the google documentation.

Comment: Looks like you have a pretty good idea here. Have you implemented a working system yet? If not, my advice would be just to do it already. It is pretty dead simple (thanks google!)

Comment: Such a response has been posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315991/design-pattern-notification-system